# Many table to union by loop function

Tags: sql-server

I have 1000 tables and I need to union all tables

table_name like `feature_20220503`, `feature_20220504` but it's not continuous numbers

It escape holiday

I want to use a loop function, but I don't know how to do it.

Does anyone could help.

Comment: dynamic sql....

Comment: *"I have 1000 tables and I need to nuion all tables"* The fact you need to `UNION ALL` 1,000 tables suggests you have a significant design flaw; probably using a table's name to denote data that should be in a column. I, personally, suggest that perhaps you need to redesign your database.

Comment: What happens when you your design changes, and you add a new column? Do you add the new column to all 1,000 of your tables, or just the new one? What happens for data integrity? Do you have a some kind of function that checks *every* table to make sure the row exists, and that function is updated every time you add a new table? Isn't that terrible for performance?

Comment: it's past three year [Futures Trading Information] by other company, their data engineer E-mail me 1000 tables include every day's Trading Information, I don't know how to do now

Comment: @陳冠儒 all tables have the same schema?

Comment: @Emka yes, it is

Comment: If the other company is emailing it to you, why are you not `INSERT`ing all that data into **one** table? Why have you created 1,000's of them? Again, *fix* your design. Having tables like this are a nightmare to work with. What would you do if someone asked for sales of a specific type, between certain dates (say a range of 100 days); right 100 odd `SELECT` statements? If you have a *good* design, it would be a simple `WHERE {Date Range Boolean Expression} AND SalesType = {Some Value}`.

Comment: @Larnu
 I don't know how to insert all that data(txt) into one table by smart method, I just use SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) import data, but it has to select one by one to a table.

Comment: SSDT is for designing database, @陳冠儒 ; do you mean SSIS? SSIS can insert into an existing table.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-tw/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/start-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver16#sql-server-management-studio-ssms

Comment: I know, but I have to select each table's target table by mouse

Comment: *"each table's target table by mouse"* Oh no... Is that really so much worse than having a flawed design? Why not just design an automated process, and then you don't have *any* mouse clicking once it's built...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make dynamic query like this

```
DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT @QUERY = @QUERY+'UNION ALL SELECT * FROM '+TABLE_NAME+CHAR(13)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'feature_%'

SET @QUERY = SUBSTRING(@QUERY,11,LEN(@QUERY))

INSERT INTO NewTable
EXEC(@QUERY)
```

Just Create new new table with the same schema as all the other tables and make sure you take only those tables from INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Comment: SET @QUERY = SUBSTRING(@QUERY,11,LEN(@QUERY))

Excuse me, what's it use??

Comment: @陳冠儒 You have to remove the first "UNION ALL" from the string creation. You can see the difference if you select the variable before and after the substring. Before the substring the EXEC(@QUERY) will end up in error.